# Firebase for Facebook Auth and Database

Tags: swift, database, facebook, io

I need to store basic/simple User Data on a Database and want to provide a Login Auth via Facebook. Should I use Firebase to do this or are there better Solutions that are still fairly simple.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is an option and it will allow you to have different Login providers. If you are only interested in FB then you can use official [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)

Comment: Yes but with Firebase I can also store data on a server securely which I cannot with Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Fireabase sounds like a framework that will give you the various components you need: authentication, database, etc.

I'd say run with Firebase until you see a reason to deviate.

The nice thing is its serverless, so you dont need to setup/manage an API or database of any type.